# What does the "source hidden state" refer to in the Attention Mechanism?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, sequence-to-sequence, attention-model

The attention weights are computed as:

[image]

I want to know what the `h_s` refers to.

In the tensorflow code, the encoder RNN returns a tuple:

```
encoder_outputs, encoder_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(...)
```

As I think, the `h_s` should be the `encoder_state`, but the [github/nmt](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/#attention-wrapper-api) gives a different answer?

```
# attention_states: [batch_size, max_time, num_units]
attention_states = tf.transpose(encoder_outputs, [1, 0, 2])

# Create an attention mechanism
attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.LuongAttention(
    num_units, attention_states,
    memory_sequence_length=source_sequence_length)
```

Did I misunderstand the code? Or the `h_s` actually means the `encoder_outputs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is probably from [this post](https://medium.com/@Synced/a-brief-overview-of-attention-mechanism-13c578ba9129), so I'll use a NN picture from the same post:

[image: nn]

Here, the `h-bar(s)` are all the blue hidden states from the *encoder* (the last layer), and `h(t)` is the current red hidden state from the *decoder* (also the last layer). One the picture `t=0`, and you can see which blocks are wired to the attention weights with dotted arrows. The `score` function is usually one of those:

[image: formula]

---

Tensorflow attention mechanism matches this picture. In theory, cell output *is* in most cases its hidden state (one exception is LSTM cell, in which the output is the short-term part of the state, and even in this case the output suits better for attention mechanism). In practice, tensorflow's `encoder_state` is different from `encoder_outputs` when the input is padded with zeros: the state is propagated from the previous cell state while the output is zero. Obviously, you don't want to attend to trailing zeros, so it makes sense to have `h-bar(s)` for these cells.

So `encoder_outputs` are exactly the arrows that go from the blue blocks upward. Later in a code, `attention_mechanism` is connected to each `decoder_cell`, so that its output goes through the context vector to the yellow block on the picture.

```
decoder_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(
    decoder_cell, attention_mechanism,
    attention_layer_size=num_units)
```